# VIM Keybindings: what key does <C-C> correspond to?

Tags: vim

i am trying to figure out vim key bindings... what key does  correspond to?  or more generally how do I read vim key bindings?   I looked at the VIM documentation but it was not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. See `:help key-notation`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @romainl's answer`:help key-notation` to find the notation of each modifier keys.

And you can use below commands to see the current mappings in your vim:

- `:nmap` Show key maps for normal mode
- `:vmap` Show key maps for visual mode
- `:imap` Show key maps for insert mode
- `:map` Show all the key maps